# Overwrite a tensor product notation a_\[TensorProduct]b_ := KroneckerProduct[a, b]

Tags: variable-definitions, tensors, debugging, products

I noticed that the definition of KroneckerProduct and

For example

```
TensorProduct[({
   {0, 1},
   {1, 0}
  }), ({
   {0, 1},
   {1, 0}
  })]
```

> Output: {{{{0,0},{0,0}},{{0,1},{1,0}}},{{{0,1},{1,0}},{{0,0},{0,0}}}}

```
KroneckerProduct[({
   {0, 1},
   {1, 0}
  }), ({
   {0, 1},
   {1, 0}
  })]
```

> Output: {{0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}}

Mathematically, what we really want for a tensor product between two matrices is indeed the **KroneckerProduct**, *NOT TensorProduct*.

I would like to define such a function:

```
a_\[TensorProduct]b_ := KroneckerProduct[a, b]
```

But it outputs a failure:

> Outputs: SetDelayed::write: Tag TensorProduct in a_[TensorProduct]b_ is Protected.

Is there a way to use the $\otimes$ namely [TensorProduct] notation to define the function     a_[TensorProduct]b_ := KroneckerProduct[a, b]?

See:[image]

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
CircleTimes[x_, y_] := KroneckerProduct[x, y]
```

or, as @CarlWoll suggested, simply

```
CircleTimes = KroneckerProduct
```

Now

```
a = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
a\[CircleTimes]a
(* {{0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Notice that it is entered as is entered as `\esc c* \esc` and not as `\esc t* \esc`. The latter is indeed reserved.

Comment: thanks but the reason to use the ⊗ symbol is to simplify the notation when we have
$$
a ⊗ b ⊗ c ⊗d ⊗ e ⊗ f ⊗ ...
$$
a long list. Othewise, how would we not just use the 
$$
\text{KroneckerProduct[a, KroneckerProduct[b,KroneckerProduct[c,...] }
$$
that is also equally long as your new function....

Comment: @wonderich See the documentation for `CircleTimes`, the very first example demonstrates exactly what you want. You may also need to use parenthesis.

Comment: thanks for the comment +1, but I really hope to use a symbol ⊗ or something else very short not like CircleTimes. But it is good to know CircleTimes[x,y, ...] 
displays as x\[CircleTimes]y\[CircleTimes]....

Comment: @wonderich As I understood, you would like to handle multiple arguments. Then you have to define corresponding rules or use parenthesis as `(a\[CircleTimes]a)\[CircleTimes]a`

Comment: Could also do `CircleTimes = KroneckerProduct`

Comment: @CarlWoll very nice, if you do not mind I amend my answer with your solution

Answer (score 1):

**For display purposes** we can define a new display format for `KroneckerProduct` like this

```
Unprotect[KroneckerProduct];
Format[x_KroneckerProduct] := Row[List @@ x,
  Subscript["\[CircleTimes]", Style["k", Tiny]]]
Protect[KroneckerProduct];

KroneckerProduct[a, b, c, d]
```

$$a\otimes _{\text{k}}b\otimes
   _{\text{k}}c\otimes
   _{\text{k}}d$$

The little "k" subscript on the $\otimes$ is there to make it a unique symbol, so there can be no question about its meaning.  It is not a required feature.

**To save a few keystrokes** and to make our input fit the language of tensor products we could define an abbreviation, `tensor`, as

```
ClearAll[tensor]
tensor = KroneckerProduct;
expr = tensor[a, b, c, d]
```

We might read this as "a tensored with b tensored with c tensored with d", or "tensor product of a, b, c and d". `expr` displays with $\otimes_k$ symbols, but is only a `KroneckerProduct` expression, as can be seen with `FullForm`.

**To remove the unique symbol definition** and return `KroneckerProduct` to its usual display form, evaluate this

```
Unprotect[KroneckerProduct];
Format[_KroneckerProduct] = Null;
Format[_KroneckerProduct] =.
Protect[KroneckerProduct];
```

The assignment of `Null` in the second line ensures there is a value to unset in the third line.